# The Library :"vector-0.12.0.2: Efficient Arrays"

Tags: haskell

I encountered the Following statement while studying a solution to create a Minesweeper program:

```
data Board = Board (V.Vector Char) Int deriving Show
```

My question is: What does it mean to put the `V.Vector Char` inside parenthesis next to the Data Constructor? Do we create an array? Of what type? What is the recommended way to create a board for a board game written in Haskell?

Comment: That's like 4 questions in one.

Answer (score 1):

In that code, `V` is probably a [qualified import](https://wiki.haskell.org/Qualified_names), like this:

```
import qualified Data.Vector as V
```

This means that whenever you need to refer to types or functions from `Data.Vector`, you'll have to supply the `V` prefix.

So `V.Vector` just means *the `Vector` type in the `Data.Vector` library*.

`V.Vector Char` then means *`Vector` of `Char`*, since `Vector` is parametrically polymorphic.

Finally, `data Board = Board (V.Vector Char) Int` declares a type called `Board` that has a data constructor, also called `Board`, that takes two arguments:

- A `V.Vector Char`
- An `Int`

So you should be able to create `Board` values by supplying a `V.Vector Char` and an `Int`.